# Как убрать лишний пробел в UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Есть окно авторизации, на котором вводит Логин и Пароль.

У поля пароля `secureTextEntry = YES`, на этом же поле есть кнопка "показать", после нажатие на которую пароль отображается, кнопка "показать" меняется на "скрыть", но после показа в поле ОТОБРАЖАЕТСЯ пробел.

Но, по сути, его нет, он только визуален (как на картинке 2), есть варианты как можно убрать этот баг?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Багом это назвать нельзя, но так работает позиционирование x,y каретки.
Чтобы пофиксить просто пропишите в методе вашего 'touchUpInside' события.]

```
NSString *value = self.textField.text;
[self.textField setText:@""];
[self.textField setText:value];
```

Comment: Спасибо, мне это помогло!